# Cannot access exposed deployment/pod in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to start out by saying I do not know the exact architecture of the servers involved.. All I know is that they are Ubuntu machines on the cloud.

I have set up a 1 master/1 worker k8s cluster using two servers.

`kubectl cluster-info` gives me:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.62.194.4:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://10.62.194.4:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

I have created a simple deployment as such:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Which spins up an nginx pod exposed on container port 80.

I have exposed this deployment using:

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx-deploy --type NodePort
```

When I run `kubectl get svc`, I get:

```
nginx-deploy   NodePort    10.99.103.239   <none>        80:30682/TCP   29m
```

`kubectl get pods -o wide` gives me:

```
nginx-deploy-7c45b84548-ckqzb   1/1     Running   0          33m   192.168.1.5   myserver1   <none>           <none>
nginx-deploy-7c45b84548-vl4kh   1/1     Running   0          33m   192.168.1.4   myserver1   <none>           <none>
```

Since I exposed the deployment using NodePort, I was under the impression I can access the deployment using `< Node IP > : < Node Port >`

The Node IP of the worker node is 10.62.194.5 and when I try to access http://10.62.194.5:30682 I do not get the nginx landing page.

One part I do not understand is that when I do `kubectl describe node myserver1`, in the long output I receive I can see:

```
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  10.62.194.5
  Hostname:    myserver1
```

Why does it say InternalIP? I can ping this IP

EDIT: 
Output of `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

```
systemd-r   846 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  24990      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       1157            root    3u  IPv4  30168      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1157            root    4u  IPv6  30170      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
xrdp-sesm  9840            root    7u  IPv6 116948      0t0  TCP [::1]:3350 (LISTEN)
xrdp       9862            xrdp   11u  IPv6 117849      0t0  TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)
kubelet   51562            root    9u  IPv4 560219      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:42735 (LISTEN)
kubelet   51562            root   24u  IPv4 554677      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:10248 (LISTEN)
kubelet   51562            root   35u  IPv6 558616      0t0  TCP *:10250 (LISTEN)
kube-prox 52427            root   10u  IPv4 563401      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:10249 (LISTEN)
kube-prox 52427            root   11u  IPv6 564298      0t0  TCP *:10256 (LISTEN)
kube-prox 52427            root   12u  IPv6 618851      0t0  TCP *:30682 (LISTEN)
bird      52925            root    7u  IPv4 562993      0t0  TCP *:179 (LISTEN)
calico-fe 52927            root    3u  IPv6 562998      0t0  TCP *:9099 (LISTEN)
```

Output of `ss -ntlp | grep 30682`

```
LISTEN   0         128                       *:30682                  *:*
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you are trying to access `10.62.194.5` from a Host which is in a different subnet, for example your terminal. In Azure I guess you have a Public IP and a Private IP for each Node. So, if you are trying to access the Kubernetes `Service` from your terminal, you should use the Public IP of the Host together with the port and also be sure that the port is open in your azure firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what I thought as well, but how can I ping the host if that is the case? I can ping and ssh into the host

Comment: Then you should try to do a `netcat` to this specific port to see if it's reachable. Try doing `nc -zvw1 10.62.194.5 30682`. If you get timeout, then the port is not open and you need to configure Azure Firewall. By the way, this IP is part of the A class private subnet which is for sure not publicly accessible. Maybe you are trying to ping a different host or you have already set up a VPN connection to this subnet.

Comment: I ran the nc command you suggested. I get this output: `nc: connect to 10.62.194.5 port 30682 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress`.. Does this mean that the port is blocked? What would the output be like if the port was not blocked

Comment: Yes this means that the port is not open. How do you have direct ssh access to this VM?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, to be honest.. Still a little bit new to all this.. I was just assigned this server and a couple more to set up a couple of clusters with the login credentials. So I just do `ssh user@ip` and set up the cluster. What would the output look like if its not blocked?

Comment: What I mean is, what would the output be like if the port is open but it times out because there is nothing running on the port

Comment: This cannot happen. You need to have a process listening to a port, to have the port open. If you want to be sure that something runs on this port, try to login into the host and run `ss -ntlp | grep 30682`. You will see that there is a `kube-proxy` listening on this port.

A successful netcat could produce something like this `Connection to 1.1.1.1 port 53 [tcp/domain] succeeded!`.

Comment: Hi I edited my question to include the results of some commands like `lsof` and `ss -ntlp | grep 30682`.. Could you please check

Comment: It's fine. I think that the problem is that there is a firewall in-between which is blocking the connection. Please check Azure firewall.

Comment: I will inform the sys admins and get back to you. Thanks a lot for the help, man.. Was stuck for quite some time on this